# Android App: Add Tablet and Smartphone Version in Google Play with <supports-screens>

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to add a tablet and a smartphone version. How can i do that in Google Play?

Do i have to set my tablet app to

```
android:xlargeScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true" 
android:normalScreens="false" 
android:smallScreens="false"
```

and my smartphone app to:

```
android:xlargeScreens="false"
android:largeScreens="false" 
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:smallScreens="true"
```

and what does

```
android:resizeable="true" 
android:anyDensity="true"
```

mean?

i´ve read the developer site informations, but i don't get it pls help me! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pls ref [Use Compatible screen][1]
```

Manifest for app targeting phones should have:

```
<compatible-screens>
<!-- all small size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
<!-- all normal size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
```

Manifest for app targeting tablet should have

```
<compatible-screens>
<!-- all large size screens 7" -->
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

<!-- all xlarge size screens 10" -->
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
```